# Explain L1 vs. L2 regularization difference using the scientific mindset

Tags: regularization, tikhonov-regularization

I need to have job interview soon, one of the questions may be L1. vs L2 regularization. Yann LeCun explained best to my knowledge the difference between L1 and L2 regularization.

> [L1 or Lasso](https://youtu.be/d9vdh3b787Y?list=PLLHTzKZzVU9eaEyErdV26ikyolxOsz6mq&t=5855): *Weights are shrunk every iteration towards zero by a constant equals to ηα. It will eliminate weights (he said inputs in error) that are not very useful.*

> [L2 or Ridge](https://youtu.be/d9vdh3b787Y?list=PLLHTzKZzVU9eaEyErdV26ikyolxOsz6mq&t=5671): *In the absence of any gradients from C the weights exponentially decay to zero. It tried to tell the system: Minimize my cost function but to it with the weight vector that is as short as possible.*

As you can see both the regularization types will minimize/eliminate the weights that are not very useful to zero. So what's the difference really? If I just say L1 will do it based on L1 norm, and L2 based on L2 norm this is probable true but that will not be the scientific mindset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When will L1 regularization work better than L2 and vice versa?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184019/when-will-l1-regularization-work-better-than-l2-and-vice-versa)