# Is number of features selected by lasso bounded by number of samples in the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, lasso, scikit-learn

I have been working on a project with fMRI data. It has a training set of 
$300 \times 21764$. I am working in python and have used lasso on it for feature selection.

For different values of the hyperparameter it sometimes selects more than $300$ features, is that possible for lasso? Or does sci-kit not use the standard lasso?

Answer (score 1):

It should not be possible for lasso, or anything with L1 penalty. Check this thread for example: [If p > n, the lasso selects at most n variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38299/if-p-n-the-lasso-selects-at-most-n-variables) 
As far as I know, scikit learn doesn't use anything nonstandard with lasso, you might get better answer on a scikit learn mailing list/github apge. Maybe it's a bug.