# Does cross-validation-chosen lambda guarantee that number of non-zero coefficient from LASSO is less than number of samples?

Tags: cross-validation, lasso

If we select 
using cross-validation, is it guaranteed that the number of non-zero coefficients is less than the sample size 
, when using cross-validation to select 
? Is there any mathematical reasoning behind this?

I understand that people have [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38299/if-p-n-the-lasso-selects-at-most-n-variables) about number of non-zeros from LASSO, but I just wanted to understand **if the cross-validation guaranteed** to pick a ̂
so that the number of nonzero is less than the sample size.

Here is my R simulation codes. `max(num_var)` is always less than `n`.

```
library(glmnet)

# Does LASSO always gives p less than n?
num_var = c()
K=500;k=1
while(k<K){
  # Simulating Data
  {
    n = 50
    p = 100
    nzc = trunc(p/10)
    x = matrix(rnorm(n * p), n, p)
    beta = rnorm(nzc)*100 # coefficient size.
    fx = x[, seq(nzc)] %*% beta
    eps = rnorm(n) 
    y = drop(fx + eps)
    px = exp(fx)
    px = px/(1 + px)
    ly = rbinom(n = length(px), prob = px, size = 1)
  }
  # Fitting LASSO
  {
    cvob1 = cv.glmnet(x, y)
  }
  # counting number of non-zero parameters.
  {
    num_var[k] = sum(!coef(cvob1)==0)
  }
  
  k=k+1
}

# No matter how large the true coefficients are, the num_var is less than n.
max(num_var)
```

Comment: It is an abuse of this site to delete your question and then repost it when it has already been closed as a duplicate.  Please see our [help] for how we work and for guidance on modifying existing questions.

Comment: @whuber Hi, I am asking a different question from what you were referring to. I would like to understand if **cross-validation** helps to select a reasonable $\lambda$ so that the number of nonzero coefficients is less than sample size $n$. By the way, I am not able to delete my previous question. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498743/is-it-guaranteed-that-number-of-non-zero-coefficient-from-lasso-with-cross-vali

Comment: The duplicate shows that cross-validation is irrelevant!  No matter what value $\lambda$ might have, at most $n$ coefficients (including the implicit intercept) will be nonzero.

Comment: @whuber You are wrong. If $\lambda$ is zero, LASSO gives $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^-XY$, which is basically elementwise not-zero beta. Here "$^-$" stands for psudo-inverse. Similarly, a small but greater-than-zero $\lambda$ gives a lot non-zero coefficients.

Comment: That is correct -- although the count of nonzero coefficients depends on which pseudo-inverse you are using.  But your point is well taken: it shows there is a genuine question here that is not obviously addressed by the apparent duplicate.